# Trying to fetch data from API in React - TypeError: recipes.map is not a function

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch, next.js

Im trying to fetch Data from an API and pass it   into my component as props. The Problem is I get this type error. Some googling showed, that  the API seems to return an object and the map() function is expecting an Array. Okay, console logged what I get from the API and it is indeed an object. Easy fix right? However, none of the fixes I found for this work. This is my original code with the error:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
const res = await fetch("https://rezepte-api-test.babafresh.de/recipes.json")
const data = await res.json()

return {

    props: { recipes: data }, // will be passed to the page component as props
}

export default function Test(recipes) {
console.log(typeof recipes);
return (
    <div>
        <ul>
            {recipes.map((recipe) =>(
                <div key={recipe.name}>
                    <li>{recipe.name}</li>
                </div>
            ))}
        </ul>
    </div>
);
```

I Did try some of the following fixes I found here, but none of my recipes from the array get rendered. Im in front of a white page, is my map function wrong here?

```
export default function Test(recipes) {

let arr = Object.entries(recipes);
return (
    <div>
        <ul>
            {arr.map((recipe) =>(
                <div key={recipe.name}>
                    <li>{recipe.name}</li>
                </div>
            ))}
        </ul>
    </div>
);
```

Id appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your first snippet, not sure this return statement at the top-level execution context is correct or what you intended to do.

```
return {

    props: { recipes: data }, // will be passed to the page component as props
}
```

And call to the receipes api returns an array not an object

[image]

So what you are doing with `Object.entries` is incorrect. Simple, use the arrayed props with the `map` function in JSX.

For the shortest fix,

`let arr = receipes.receipes;`

P.S. If you think this set of API data is only meant for this component and will not be shared, try using the `useEffect` hook to fetch the data inside this component itself and render.

```
    export default function Test() {
    const [receipes, setReceipes] = useState('');
    
    useEffect(() => setReceipes(await fetch("https://rezepte-api-test.babafresh.de/recipes.json").then(res => res.json())), []);
    
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {receipes.map((recipe) =>(
                    <div key={recipe.name}>
                        <li>{recipe.name}</li>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
     );
  }
```

Comment: I have no prior experience with useEffect hook but I will give it a try.  As for using the arrayed props with the map function, isnt that exactly what I tried to do in the first code snippet? (inside the <ul>). 

thank you for the help

Comment: You should use useEffect, it's the React way to do it. Read the first part of my answer: I don't understand why you returned something in the air and also that you got an object as the response instead of an array, which is incorrect. Apart from that, I see your log from Object.entries and you are messing up getting the value from the object. Do `receipes.receipes` instead of `Object.entries`

Comment: @AakashVerma I think initially `receipes` needs to be blank array else it will try to map on blank string and then give error.

Comment: I tried it with the useEffect hook but still run into TypeError: receipes.map is not a function

Comment: @PriyankKachhela that is what `useState([])` provides. An empty array to start with.

Comment: @sontiyo seems like you were able to solve it. Not sure why but if you are getting data like `{receipes: [...]}`, you should read it as `receipes.receipes` like I told you. Apart from all of this, remember to introspect.

Answer (score 1):

The API is returning an array of objects only.

[image: Response from API]

To access the data from the API, you can just `map` over it as it an `array`

```jsx
    <div>
        <ul>
            {res.data.map((recipe) =>(
                <div key={recipe.name}>
                    <li>{recipe.name}</li>
                </div>
            ))}
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did in the first code snippet, all I was missing was the .data is what u are saying? Trying out your snippet, I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

(I replaced res with my props called 'recipes' which I pass to component

Answer (score 0):

Are you using useEffect? Usually these problems are related to async fetching and initially getting undefined or empty lists etc. as a prop before data is actually available. If you are using effect, then try to catch the first error by calling map only if recipes is defined.

For your second solution: check the contents of arr by logging it.

Comment: I am not using useEffect. 
If I log the content of my array I get the following output:

[
  [
    'recipes',
    [
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object]
    ]
  ]
]